# RESTEasy - Stacktrace in logs when throwing WebApplicationException

Tags: resteasy

I am using Resteasy 2.3.3, bundled with JBoss-AS-7.1.3.  I'm trying to
throw a new WebAppliationException, and the output (to the client) seems
fine, but I'm left with an unwanted stack trace in my log.  I have a few
other Exceptions mapped, and I was wondering if the mapping was somehow
causing an issue ­ trying to wrap this Exception.

Simple example:

```
public class SimpleService {
@GET
@Path("stuff")
public String getStuff(final @QueryParam("param1") String param1,
  @QueryParam("param2") String param2) throws ActionException {
  if (param1==null && param2==null) {
    throw new WebApplicationException();
  }
```

I get the following exception:

```
[WARN] org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher#error - failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException
```

Any ideas what this error might mean?  How I could get rid of the messages?

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled across another class in the javadoc - NoLogWebApplicationException, and it says:

> WebApplicationExceptions are logged by RESTEasy. Use this exception
>   when you don't want your exception logged

https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.3.Final/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/spi/NoLogWebApplicationException.html